# Applying Style to last li in a ul with CSS / Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li><div>Some content</div></li>
   <li><div>some more content</div></li>
   <li><div>final content</div></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to apply a top border around each div. On the last div I would like to put a bottom border. I am targeting IE7/8. I have the top border working fine, I need help getting the bottom border.

I've tried:

```
   ul > li:last-child > div
    {
        border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }
```

I've also tried using last-type-of.

I am looking for a CSS solution and a Jquery solution

Comment: Thanks Paolo....didn't even notice the html was lost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you have a `<div>` inside the `<li>`? Completely possible without that.

Anyways, this is how to do it with jQuery:

```
$('ul > li:last-child > div').css('border-bottom','1px solid black');
```

Comment: Well Good question might not need it, I needed a background color, as different things in the list have different color backgrounds. I don't think it worked when I put the background on the li but now that I think about it that might have been an unrelated issue

Comment: I like your approach over adding the class, as this doesn't require me to change my markup. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Be sure you understand the difference between :last-child and :last in jquery. From their docs: :last-child matches all elements that are the last child of their parent.
While :last matches only a single element, this matches more then one: One for each parent.

Comment: @Scott: I would imagine that's the behavior desired. If you have several ULs you would want to put the border on each last child. Thanks for the note, though.

Answer (score 5):

**:last-child** is CSS3, unlike **:first-child** which was introduced in CSS2, and has no IE support while. I believe the following is the safest way to implement it using jquery

```
$('li').last().addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a CSS only solution:

Apply the bottom border to the ul. To make it work cross-browser, remove the padding from the ul and bump the list over with a margin.

```
ul.border {border-bottom:1px solid #000;padding:0;margin-left:40px;}
ul.border li {border-top:1px solid #000;}

<ul class="border">
   <li>Some content</li>
   <li>some more content</li>
   <li>final content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`:last-child` doesn't work in IE7 (not sure on IE8), so you'll have to do the jQuery route. Your css lines up pretty much the same way the selectors would work in jQuery:

```
$('ul > li:last > div').addClass('someclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you need the "`<div>`" inside the "`<li>`" but if you don't need it you could simply use:

```
ul > li:last-child {
```

I tested it and work for me in chrome, ie8, firefox and safari.

Comment: last-child didn't work on IE7....don't recall why I had a div in the li...been to long

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourUL li:last div").css({'border-bottom':'solid 1px black'});
```